# Passing Hidden Fields to another aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to pass data from one aspx page to another using hidden fields.

On pageone.aspx, in the page_load, I am saving data into a hidden field:

```
ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("var1", "hello");
```

Then, the user clicks on a button on pageone.aspx, which redirects to pagetwo.aspx

```
Response.Redirect(Constant.AdminUser, true);
```

Then, in the page_load of pagetwo.aspx, I grab pageone's hiddenfield by:

```
Request.Params["var1"]
```

But nothing is returned.

For some reason, when I replace Response.Redirect with `Server.Transfer`, I get data in `pagetwo.aspx`, which is what I want. But the browser's URL does not change.

I want to be able to pass in data from pageone to pagetwo, without storing the data in the session variable, url, database, cache, etc. I would like to send it using hidden field.

Comment: Normally it is done via client side POST, but you seem to need server side... Would adding parameters to redirect Url work for you?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a full article on handling cross-page posting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx

TL;DR: You have to register the previous page using the @PreviousPageType declaration, then call against the PreviousPage property.

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similiar and all I did was erasing my `Server.Transfer` line and keep PostBackUrl on my button.

If you have them both, your URL won't change.

Comment: It might help more if you provided a some code example to demonstrate your answer.